# How to iterate through an array of hashes when there is a blank hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes: `@grouped_messages` =

```
[{},
{100=>[#<Message id: 3, content: "Needs more training", from: 100, employee_id: 1>]},
{101=>[#<Message id: 2, content: "Very lazy.", from: 101, employee_id: 2>], 102=>[#<Message id: 1, content: "Fantastic.", from: 102, employee_id: 2>]}]
```

One of the hashes is blank.

How can I iterate through the array and display the contents without causing the following error:

```
Error (undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass)
```

I have tried the following but I still get the error:

```
<% if @grouped_messages.any? %>
 <% @grouped_messages.each do |sender, messages| %>
  <% if messages.any? %>
   <% messages.each do |msg| %>
      ....
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You should remove the empty hash when creating `@grouped_messages` in your controller

Comment: Could use `next` to skip something you do not want in iteration.

Answer (score 3):

I'd filter to keep only non empty hashes:

```
@grouped_messages.reject(&:blank?).each ...
```

Comment: It would give error like undefined method `blank?' for {...}:Hash

Comment: @AlokAnand no, active support provides this method

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out empty Hashes like apneadiving suggests. However, there is another mistake in your code.

`@grouped_messages` is an Array of Hashes. You cannot do

```
@grouped_messages.each do |sender, messages|
```

Using `.each` on an Array yields a *single value*, in your case that's a Hash. So you should do:

```
@grouped_messages.each do |grouped_message|
  grouped_message.each do |sender, messages|
  # ...
  end
end
```

In your case, your `messages` variable is always `nil`, as the Hash (e.g., `{100=>[ ... ]}`) will be stored in the `sender` variable. So it's `nil` even with non-empty Hashes.

In fact, looking at your data, it's better to make `@grouped_messages` a Hash instead, with as keys the sender ids and the values a list of Messages. So have a structure like:

```
@grouped_messages = { 
  101 => [ msg1, msg2, ... msgN ],
  102 => [ msg1, msg2, ... msgN ]
}
```

Then you can do your loop just fine:

```
@grouped_messages.each do |sender, messages|
  # ...    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% @grouped_messages.reject(&:blank?).each do |sender, messages| %>
  <% messages.each do |msg| %>
    # ....
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The empty Hash would yield `true` when used in an `if` statement: `{} ? "true" : "false" # => "true"`. Only `nil` and `false` yield false as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the condition

```
if messages.any?
```

and change the next line to

```
messages.to_a.each do |msg|
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete empty messages with pure Ruby

```
@grouped_messages.reject(&:empty?)
```